# Why in Bliss-OS Android 12 x86 Not working the Touch screen?

Tags: touchscreen, android-x86

I have Evoo EV-T2in1-116-1 Windows tablet. Because it lagging, I decided to install Android x86 12(*Bliss-OS*) and touch screen not working. What can I do? Touchscreen is **Kionix**.

Comment: Sorry, but your question appears to be off-topic to stack overflow, which is about programming questions. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic